# PHP string intersections, greedily strip left from right

Tags: php, string, substring, intersection

I'm looking to strip a string, `$left` from the left of another string, `$right`. Given:

```
$left  = 'alpha beta gamma';
$right = 'beta gamma delta';
```

The desired output would be:

```
string(6) " delta"
```

Now, I've sort of accomplished this. I've written a function, to achieve this exactly:

```
function strip_left_from_right($left, $right){
    for($i = 0, $m = strlen($left); $i <= $m; $i++){
        $needle = substr($left, -$i);
        if(substr($right, 0, strlen($needle)) == $needle){
            return substr($right, strlen($needle));
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine. However I want it to be be "*greedy*", using as much of the `$left` string as possible. For instance:

```
$left  = "foofoofoofoo";
$right = "foofoofoobar";

// desired output
string(3) "bar"

// actual output
string(9) "foofoobar"
```

Essentially my question is two-fold;

**1. What would be the best way to perform a "*greedy*" match? (*given I continue with this code*)**

And probably more important;

**2. Is there a better (*non-iterative, set of core functions used in tandem*) way to accomplish this?**

---

The solution I went with, thanks to @Yoshi for getting my brain in that direction:

```
function intersect_split($left, $right, $greedy = true){
    for($i = 0, $m = strlen($left); $i <= $m; $i++){
        $chunk = substr($left, $i * (int) ($greedy ?: -1));
        if(substr($right, 0, strlen($chunk)) == $chunk){
            return array(
                (string) substr($left, 0, $m - strlen($chunk)),
                (string) substr($right, strlen($chunk)),
            );
        }
    }
    return array($left, $right);
}

$left  = 'foo bar bar bar bar';
$right = 'bar bar bar bar baz';

var_dump( intersect_split($left, $right, true) );
var_dump( intersect_split($left, $right, false) );
```

Produces:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "foo "
  [1]=>
  string(4) " baz"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "foo bar bar bar "
  [1]=>
  string(16) " bar bar bar baz"
}
```

So now I essentially split the string at an intersecting match of the right of the `$left` argument and left of the `$right` argument, producing the leading and trailing strings in an array. `$greedy` produces the obvious difference in results.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing that?

Comment: @Pezhvak - General purpose string manipulation. Several instances where this is useful in an application I'm working on.

Comment: It looks similar to a diff system, you may be interested in a diff implementation there https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/5bfe1d2a8f967c7901ace50f04ac2d9308ed3169/simplediff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not optimal, but at least it does the job:

```
function helper($left, $right) {
    $match = '';

    for ($i = strlen($left) - 1; $i >= 0; $i -= 1) {
        $chunk = substr($left, $i);
        $len = strlen($chunk);
        if (substr($right, 0, $len) == $chunk && $len > strlen($match)) {
            $match = $chunk;
        }
    }

    return substr($right, strlen($match));
}

echo helper('alpha beta gamma', 'beta gamma delta'); // output " delta"
echo helper('foofoofoofoo', 'foofoofoobar'); // output "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi - Your answer got me thinking in the direction I needed for sure; see question for solution, I'll mark yours accepted since it got me there :)